# Why aren't launchCamera and launchImageLibrary functions available for react-native-image-picker?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working on a React Native project with `^0.22.8 react-native-image-picker`, but I am getting an error that `ImagePicker` is undefined (it is imported like: `import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker'`). So I console log `ImagePicker` and it only had a `showImagePicker` function. I `npm install react-native-image-picker@latest --save` installed it.

So I cloned the Example project from https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker/tree/master/Example and did npm installed, and it worked perfectly fine. So I console log `ImagePicker` and it actually logged 3 functions: `showImagePicker`, `launchImageCamera`, and `launchCamera`.

Why is there a difference when I properly installed it? What could I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After `npm install`, you need to do `react-native link`.